# How to permanently remove directory in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, directory

**I have a directory I want to remove in /opt/**

```
[user /] $ sudo su
[root /] # cd /opt
[root opt] # rm -rf tomcat9
[root opt] # ls
[root opt] # ls
tomcat9
```

But i still cannot seem to remove the tomcat9 directory. There are still nested directories inside tomcat9 (/opt/tomcat9/openam/openam/debug/SystemCore) but `rm -rf tomcat9` as root should remove it.

There are no errors when i remove. It did actually remove but after a few seconds, `tomcat9` directory reappeared again. Why is that?

Comment: Someone or something recreated it.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Server Fault.

As @Michael said, the directory cannot re-appear magically. Someone maybe recreated it, or you didn't wrote down the command correctly... it's difficult to say what happened, but no magic here.

Comment: I managed to fix it! I checked the users which i added earlier and killed the process and deleted the user which was recreating the file. After that `rm -rf tomcat9` worked beautifully.

Comment: Haha, glad you found out :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the tomcat server.
This recreates the directory you've removed.